# Laravel : How to use eloquent ORM to find information of NOT authenticated user?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I have this function to get the info of a user who is currently logged in.

```
$users = User::get();
$loginuser = $users->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

How do I use Laravel's eloquent ORM to get other users and put it in an array variable? Maybe something like

```
$otherusers = $users->find(not(Auth::user()->id));
```

Of course, it will **not work** but you get what I mean. Bonus points for improvement of the first 2 lines above~! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this to get all the users other than the logged in user:

```
$otherusers = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

If you use `Auth::user()` then you'll get only the currently logged in user. So for example:

```
// Logged In user, You can directly use
// Auth::user()->id or any property, no
// need keep it in a variable for that
$loggedInUser = Auth::user(); // Returns a single Model

// Other users (Returns a collection of user models)
// Check if a user is logged in before you use Auth::user()->id
$otherusers = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: +1 Just make sure there's actually a user logged in. Otherwise you'll get an error with this code.